# insert statement from mysql 5.5.68 not working in 8.0.31

Tags: php, mysql

This sql statement work perfectly fine in mysql 5.5

```
INSERT INTO invoices SET LocationsID = "5399", InvoiceDisplayID = "6343088", Generated = NOW()
```

but now in mysql 8.0 I get the following errors

```
Static analysis:

3 errors were found during analysis.

Unexpected token. (near "," at position 75)
Unexpected token. (near "Generated" at position 77)
Unrecognized statement type. (near "Generated" at position 77)
SQL query:

INSERT INTO invoices SET LocationsID = "5399", InvoiceDisplayID = "6343088", Generated = NOW()

MySQL said: Documentation

#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'Generated = NOW()' at line 1
```

it seems that if I modify the sql statement to this

```
INSERT INTO invoices(
    LocationsID,
    InvoiceDisplayID,
    Generated
)
SELECT
    '5399',
    '6343088',
    NOW()
```

then it doesn't complain and works fine.

so why is this happening and is there a way to make mysql 8.0 work like 5.5 did for the original insert sql?

thanks!

Comment: You want `INSERT INTO ... VALUES (...)` : https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/insert.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`GENERATED` was added as a [reserved keyword](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/keywords.html) in MySQL 5.7.6.

You can use backticks to escape it:

```
INSERT INTO invoices SET ... `Generated` = NOW()
```

Comment: You could have just closed this as a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23446377/syntax-error-due-to-using-a-reserved-word-as-a-table-or-column-name-in-mysql

Comment: Yeah maybe, I wasn't aware of that question.